# Passar um int array 2d para outra activity

Tags: android

Tenho este *array*:

`int[][] meuArray= new int[5][3];`

Como envio este *array* para uma outra atividade?

Se fosse um *array* 1d bastava fazer `intent.putExtra("Array", meuArray);` para enviar e o *array* e fazer 
`array = getIntent().getIntArrayExtra("Array");` para receber. Porém for com um *array* bidimensional isto já não resulta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A classe *Intent* usa internamente um [Bundle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) para guardar os valores passados ao método `putExtra()`.

A classe disponibiliza várias versões(overloading/sobrecarga) do método `putExtra()`, entre eles um que recebe um *serializable*, como é o caso de qualquer tipo de *Array*.

Ao usar

```
int[][] meuArray= new int[5][3];
...
...
intent.putExtras("meuArray", meuArray);
```

o método sobrecarregado usado é [putExtra(String name, Serializable value)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.io.Serializable)).

Assim, para recuperar o array original, deve usar o método [getSerializableExtra(String name)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getSerializableExtra(java.lang.String)) e não [getIntArrayExtra(String name)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getIntArrayExtra(java.lang.String)):

```
String[][] meuArray = (int[][])getIntent().getSerializableExtra("meuArray");
```

---

**Nota:** Parece que [existe um *"bug"*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/171834/2541) no Android 4 em que é lançado o erro

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to int[][]

ao fazer *cast* do retorno do método para `int[][]`.

Se for o caso, use

```
Object[] vector;
int[][] meuArray;

vector = (Object[])getIntent().getSerializableExtra("meuArray");
meuArray = Arrays.copyOf(vector, vector.length, int[][].class);
```

para recuperar o array.