# Erro java.lang.ClassCastException ao usar getSerializable() na API 16

Tags: android, android-sdk

Tenho 2 emuladores, Nexus 5 API 23 e o Nexus One API 16.
No Nexus 5 o programa corre direito, no Nexus One o programa crasha e o erro que dá é `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to int[][]`

Dá erro aqui: `meuArray=(int[][]) extras.getSerializable("array");`

Como é que é possivel o mesmo código dar bem num emulador e mal no outro? Tem haver com as API´s?

EDIT:

```
int[][] position = new int[5][3];

if(sentado[indice].isChecked()){//Esta parte tem mais if´s mas fazem a mesma coisa que este, so varia os indices
    position[0][0]++;}

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("array", position);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

Comment: O problema deve ser antes disso, deve ser no `put`, só tem como saber se tiver algum exemplo da parte do `put`.

Comment: Fiz outro teste, corri o programa em 2 emuladores Nexus One, só que um tinha a API 16 e outro a 23.
No que tinha a API 23 deu certinho, no que tinha API 16 crashou e ficou com algumas partes do layout deformadas. 
Por isso eu acho que deve ser mesmo da API @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: Como eu disse o problema é no momento do `put` provavelmente, sem código não dá pra ter certeza como isso desencadeia, quero dizer é culpa do emulador, mas é no put e não no get, se não colocar o código não dá pra ter certeza. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: ja postei algum codigo @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: Acredito que o problema seja que `java.lang.Object[]` deveria ser `java.lang.Object[][]`, talvez alguns valores sejam `null`

Comment: Eu inicializo todas as variaveis(nao postei porque era muito grande) por isso acho que nenhum é null @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: Isso `int position = new int[5][3];` não deveria ser isso `int[][] position = new int[5][3];`?

Comment: É, eu é que me esqueci de passar para aqui, no meu código está bem @GuilhermeNascimento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo esta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36083034/2556111) no SOen parece ser um bug no Android 4.

A forma sugerida para resolver é fazer o *cast* do retorno do método para `Object[]` e usar o método `Arrays.copyOf()` para obter o *array* original:

```
Object[] vector;
int[][] meuArray;

vector = (Object[])extras.getSerializable("array");
meuArray = Arrays.copyOf(vector, vector.length, int[][].class);
```